# Storing a reference to an element dynamically added by append

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have added a new element dynamically through jQuery like this:

```
var elem = $('#unique').append($('<span>').attr('data-rollNo', i));
```

Now I need to use this element after this to add something to it. Is there a way I can store a reference to this element here, so I done need to search the entire DOM every time I edit this?

Comment: Yes, there is a way. What have you tried?

Comment: Interesting, how is this off-topic. OP posted clear question, with code he tried. And still it's closed. Something is very wrong about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`appendTo`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) method instead of [`append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/):

```
var $span = $('<span>').attr('data-rollNo', i).appendTo('#unique');
```

Now, span is appended and you also have a reference to this new object.